# How to execute ida-decompiler python script from IDAPython inside IDA Pro

Tags: python, plugins, decompiler, ida

I'm trying to execute this python script in IDA PRO using IDAPython.

https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/ida-decompiler

It says to run this script you simply just do the following

> This is an IDA plugin which can decompile one function at a time. To
>   try it in IDA, place your cursor on a function, and execute the
>   plugin. The decompiled function will appear in the output window.

I placed my mouse cursor on the assembly code of a function.
I don't know whats the hotkey to run the script.
I already loaded the script by doing <kbd>Alt+F9</kbd> then pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> key and loading up the `decompiler.py`

All it said in the Output window was `Using IDA backend.`
I'm guessing it's loaded now.

There must be a hotkey to use this script when I place the mouse over the assembly code of a function nothing is outputted in the `Output window`.
Right clicking the assembly code has no new menu options and clicking `Edit->Plugins` doesn't have any new plugins.

**EDIT:** Looking here https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/ida-decompiler/blob/3bd9ea6a1c073e68fef33e3cf092a34ca7fdd763/src/host/ida/ui/main.py

seems the hotkey should be `F5` same as Hex-Rays Decompiler (Could they both use the same hotkey?).
It should output the errors either.
`Failed to register hotkey!`
`Hotkey unregistered!`
`Press F5 to decompile a function.`
`Failed to delete hotkey!`

None of that is outputted in `Output Window` and `F5` just runs Hex-Rays.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://code.google.com/p/idapython/wiki/UsageInstructions

or change to the right ida version - ida python version:
http://code.google.com/p/idapython/downloads/list

best regards